# How to configure servers on LAN to emulate no-ip.com functionality with dnsmasq and apache wildcard subdomains?

Tags: apache-2.2, router, dnsmasq, wildcard-subdomain, dynamic-ip

I have a multi workstation LAN with Apache2 serving a website at 10.0.0.3:80 and running on Ubuntu Linux. This LAN is segmented from another LAN via a router, from which all machines on this LAN receive their IP's.

Is the following concept feasible or is there a more sensible way?

The goal is to make the LAN behave similarly to how no-ip.com functions on the Internet.  With this in mind, I would like to setup one of the workstations with CentOS 6 and configure it as a DNS server and an apache webserver that is configured for wildcard subdomains. All subdomains from this server shall point to the website on the Ubuntu server at IP 10.0.0.3:80.

So that, for example, with a domain of local.lan on the CentOS server, any requests from any browser on the LAN, i.e. for *wildcard.local.lan, will be resolved to the site residing on the Ubuntu webserver, while all non local addresses are directed to the Internet.

Some of my concerns are:

Will dnsmasq suffice as the dns server in this configuration?  What are some key configuration notes for dnsmasq and apache in this multi server configuration?  Will I still be able to use the router for the IP's?  Are there simpler alternatives?l